# Magento 2.1 upgrade error: Table 'sequence_salesrule' already exists

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, magento-2.1, magento2-enterprise

I upgraded to Magento 2.1 and now I'm getting the following error doing `bin/magento setup:upgrade`:

```
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
Cache cleared successfully
[...skip...]
Module 'Magento_SalesRuleStaging':
Installing schema... 

  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sequence_salesrule' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE sequence_salesrule (
                       sequence_value integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                       PRIMARY KEY (sequence_value)
              ) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1                                             

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sequence_salesrule' already exists
```

I remove the database table by running this SQL:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DROP TABLE sequence_salesrule; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Now I get the following error when running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` again:

```
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
Cache cleared successfully
[...skip...]
Module 'Magento_SalesRuleStaging':
Installing schema... 

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'row_id'
```

I can't find that column anywhere. If I knew where that column would be, then I could remove it and try to run the command again...

Comment: You're using EE version?

Comment: Since Staging is an Enterprise-only feature, I would recommend reaching out to Magento support.

Comment: @7ochem, if you solved this issue then can you please share it's solutions .